# How can I right align my div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image with the text underneath it which I've achieved but I want it inline with the paragraph text on the right hand side like you'd see on wikipedia or something.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="img-with-text"; style= text-align: right; >
<img src="250px-PeterAndWendy.png" alt="Title page, 1911 U.S. edition" 
 align="right">
        <p> Title page, 1911 U.S. edition </p> 
        </div>

<p> a bunch of text </p>
```

and my css:

```
 /* makes text stay under image */
 .img-with-text {
 text-align: justify;
 width: 250px;

 }

.img-with-text img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: right;
```

I want it to be like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGNJ6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

By using `float` property in css, you can easily push/pull an element into the right/left.

```css
.pull-right{
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

img{
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #000000;
  padding: 5px;
}


.center{
  text-align: center;
}

p.center{
  margin: 0;
}

.body{
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="center">Title page, 1911 U.S. edition</h3>
<div class="pull-right">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGNJ6.png" alt="Title page, 1911 U.S. edition">
  <p class="center">Img txt</p>
</div>

<p class="body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ut mattis dui. Nam viverra erat ac ullamcorper scelerisque. Nunc eget augue ex. Proin eleifend velit porttitor velit tristique, in viverra est pulvinar. Sed aliquam rhoncus hendrerit. Nunc at lectus sodales, vestibulum odio ac, vehicula eros. Etiam congue hendrerit lectus sit amet commodo. Vestibulum gravida, sapien non porta tempus, urna turpis tempor quam, id placerat arcu ligula lacinia magna.Nunc suscipit tincidunt vulputate. Quisque mi risus, hendrerit gravida euismod a, ullamcorper ut quam. Nulla ornare metus at est accumsan varius. Etiam scelerisque est nulla, vel scelerisque est facilisis ut. Phasellus ac ullamcorper quam. Integer ante massa, accumsan nec lacus id, finibus luctus nisi. Quisque sed mollis mauris, et egestas elit. Suspendisse malesuada mi vel urna lobortis, id hendrerit sapien consectetur. 
</p>
```